# Why is water leaking behind my new rain gutter?

Tags: gutters

We had gutters installed by a contractor and we noticed water leaking from the back. The water appears to be rolling from the roof, over the roof apron, over the fascia, and then down the back of the gutter (see picture below). Most diagrams (see example below) I've seen online show that the gutter should have been installed under the roof apron, and the fascia should have been extended down to support the gutter. Is my understanding correct?

Lastly, they routed the downspout around some conduit on my house with 3 pieces of straight pieces (see picture below). Is there a better way to do this? This seems sloppy to me.

[image: Gutter Installation]
[image: Diagram]
[image: Conduit and Downspout]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is partly that your drip edge isn't dripping. It may have been pulled too tight when it was installed, causing it to lay too flat. It's not really a gutter problem. The fact that rainwater was running down the fascia was an issue that needed resolution anyway.

You can try to adjust your drip edge by flexing it downward, but it may be better to fit some flashing behind it that extends into the gutter. You can purchase suitable galvanized steel or aluminum from a home supply store and cut it to fit.

The downspout solution seems ok to me. The only bends available are much too large for that situation. It shouldn't be a problem at all unless there's a blockage.

Comment: Ditto on the down spout. The only other solution would have been to stand the spout off from the wall by 1.5 inches and the necessary blocking on the wall to accommodate the spout brackets would have been way uglier.

Comment: You can get #0 elbows, I think they're 20° - 25°, or zig zag elbows which only stick out about 2", would look better, but looks like they did what they could with what they had.